# How to create moment 1 map (also known as velocity filed or velocity map) using python?

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, fits

I need to create a moment 1 map using Python and I cannot use SpectralCube package to produce it (.moment(order=1) method). The problem is I've stucked and basically everything I write is just a garbage. Does anyone have an experience with moment maps and can help with that?
I'm working with cubes and I handle fits using astropy.
Just to make you sure what I mean I'll put an explanation from CASA documentation:
[Moments explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60rwA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow isn't the best place to ask this question; you'd likely benefit from asking on an astronomy-specific forum.

That said, the most likely reason your moment-1 map would look like garbage is if you include a lot of noise.  Since the first moment is the intensity-weighted coordinate, if you have a large cube with a lot of noisy pixels, you may get only noise out.  A good approach is to [mask](https://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/masking.html) the data before computing the [moments](https://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moments.html).  If you use only pixels with significant detections above the noise, the moment maps will generally come out clean.